# How to convert different formats of date into one format using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Input: A date field that includes date in various formats (including: `yyyy/dd/mm`, `dd-mm-yyyy`, etc.), for example:

```
2017/5/23
22-04-2015
20150504
```

Output: date field in a uniform format. All date values should be converted to the `yyyymmdd` format. i.e. above input should generate output as:

```
20170523
20150422
20150504
```

I tried using `dateutils` but the output format is 2015-05-23

```
from datetime import datetime
INPUT_FILENAME = 'date.txt'
OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'newfile.txt'
INPUT_DATE_FORMATS = {'column1dt': '%Y%m%d', 'column1dt': '%d/%m/%Y'}
OUTPUT_DATE_FORMAT = '%Y%m%d'
with open(INPUT_FILENAME, 'rt') as finput:
reader = finput.readlines()
with open(OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wt') as foutput:
    print foutput 
    for row in reader:
```

Comment: also you can convert date into ordinal date and convert it back to any desire format

Comment: @reddy, What is your input? Is it of type string?

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you can guess the format of a date string:

```
import datetime

def guess_date(string):
    for fmt in ["%Y/%m/%d", "%d-%m-%Y", "%Y%m%d"]:
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(string, fmt).date()
        except ValueError:
            continue
    raise ValueError(string)
```

With the sample bellow:

```
samples = "2017/5/23", "22-04-2015", "20150504"

for sample in samples:
    print(guess_date(sample))
```

You get:

```
2017-05-23
2015-04-22
2015-05-04
```

Use `d.strftime("%Y%m%d")` to choose your desired format:

```
for sample in samples:
    d = guess_date(sample)
    print(d.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

You can also use [dateutil.parser](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) to parse a date in any format.

See example:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import *
>>> now = parse("Sat Oct 11 17:13:46 UTC 2003")
```

Comment: Do you need more explanation? If not, I suggest you to upvote and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471) my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

```
import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime('22-04-2015', '%d-%m-%Y')
datetime_output = datetime_object.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Then you change the format of the date to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. This answer makes it simpler to understand the general gist of it. Together with https://strftime.org/ 